# Xamarin's MAC Demo not launched from Launch Pad

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I am using LiveSwitch's Xamarin ClientSDK Example. When I am running the Demo example from Visual studio for MAC in DEBUG mode, then it is working fine. 
After this, I have created the package(.pkg) file from this demo and installed it in my MAC system. But the app did not launch from LaunchPad.

I tried the Demo of version number LiveSwitch-1.3.4.7439 but it didn't work for me, so I downloaded the version LiveSwitch-1.5.1.10002 and checked the same after creating the package and facing the same issue.

Are there any configuration-related changes or something else that I need to apply at the "MAC system" level or at the "Visual Studio for MAC" level or at the "Project" level or something else?

ScreenShot of configuration for my MAC's system and Visual Studio for MAC is attached herewith for your reference.

I request to guide me on this.

Thanks 
Vivek

Comment: Do you test SDK by [this](https://help.frozenmountain.com/docs/liveswitch/clients/macos)  ?  And attached file not uploaded in question .

Comment: I am using the SDK code of [Xamarin.macOS](https://help.frozenmountain.com/docs/liveswitch/clients/xamarin-macos). I downloaded it from FM's website and created the package(.pkg) and install it to MAC. Then I tried to run the demo application from the launching but unfortunately, it didn't launch. It just crashed from the launchpad.